# "Beim Einfügen bzw. Ändern von Daten..." vs. "Beim Einfügen bzw. beim Ändern von Daten..."

Tags: grammar

Welche Variante ist stilistisch vorzuziehen (in einem formellen, geschriebenen Text)? Ist das zweite "beim" grammantikalisch notwendig oder nicht?

Wenn nicht: Gibt es für dieses Konstrukt einen Fachbegriff?

EDIT: Vergleiche auch "Beim Einfügen bzw. bei Änderung der Daten" - hier ist das "bei" meines Wissens auf jeden Fall erforderlich.

Comment: Definitiv die erste Version, zumal wenn du bzw. abkürzt. Das gibt dem Text einen Charakter von Kürze, den das zweite "beim" wieder kaputt machen würde.

Answer (score 3):

Das zweite "beim" wird grammatikalisch gesehen nicht benötigt. Ein Fachbegriff hierfür ist mir jedoch nicht bekannt.

EDIT: Zu Deinem Edit: Ja, das ist dort erforderlich.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn eine Frage nach Stil gestellt wird, muss darauf hingewiesen werden, dass es die Lesbarkeit verbessert, wenn man auf Abkürzungen verzichtet.

Das geht in dem genannten Beispiel auch recht einfach durch die Konjunktion **"oder"**. Das Resultat muss allerdings an den nachfolgenden, nicht genannten Kontext angepasst werden:

> Wenn Daten geändert oder eingefügt werden, ...
>   Das Einfügen oder Ändern von Daten *muss/kann/führt zu/...*

Ein Artikel kann bei Aufzählungen im Plural auch ganz weggelassen werden:

> Ergänzungen oder Änderungen der Daten...